# Can I mount a case-insensitive tmpfs/ramfs?

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, mount, tmpfs

I would like to utilize the performance of tmpfs/ramfs for some file operations, but the programs/processes that use these files assume a case-insensitive file system. I cannot find any documentation for tmpfs/ramfs options that would allow case-insensitivity (which I completely expect).

Are there other methods for achieving similar results? [How] can I get a case-insensitive tmpfs/ramfs?

(Note: Looking for answers for RHEL/CentOS 7, but could easily switch to another distro if it has a good solution.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following to create a case insensitive filesystem in /tmp:

```
truncate -s 100M /tmp/vfat
losetup /dev/loop0 /tmp/vfat
mkfs.vfat /dev/loop0
mkdir /mnt/vfat
mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/vfat
```

If you don't want to use tmpfs but ramfs instead, create a RAM mount first:

```
mkdir /mnt/ramfs
mount -t ramfs -o size=110M ramfs /mnt/ramfs
```

Then follow the steps above to create the vfat placeholder file, filesystem and mount.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ciopfs](http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs/) stackable filesystem, which implements a case-insensitive filesystem on top of a case-sensitive one.

```
mkdir /tmp/case-sensitive /tmp/case-insensitive
ciopfs /tmp/case-sensitive /tmp/case-insensitive
TMPDIR=/tmp/case-insensitive myapp
fusermount -u /tmp/case-insensitive
```

Ciopfs is a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem, which is available on most Unix variants including Linux. You may need to explicitly allow the user running that application to use FUSE (I don't know whether RHEL allows users to use FUSE by default).

Stacking a filesystem will inevitably cause a small performance penalty, but it's only a CPU cost, no disk I/O cost.